# Sorting list of strings by substring

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort this list

```
list = ['16. Michlík', '4. and 65. Bichakhchyan', '15. Pavol']
```

according to first number of each string. So that output should look like this

```
list = ['4. and 65. Bichakhchyan', '15. Pavol', '16. Michlík']
```

This is what I have so far, but it does not work when there is more then one number in string

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x : x[:x.find(".")])
```

Can you guys help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must cast the pattern to an integer, otherwise it is compared as a string.

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x : int(x[:x.find(".")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
l = ['16. Michlík', '4. and 65. Bichakhchyan', '15. Pavol']
result = sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(re.findall('^\d+', x)[0]))
```

Output:

```
['4. and 65. Bichakhchyan', '15. Pavol', '16. Michlík']
```

Comment: You can replace `re.findall('^\d+', x)[0]` with `re.match(r'\d+', x).group()` for some free performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
lst = ['16. Michlík', '4. and 65. Bichakhchyan', '15. Pavol']

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

# ['4. and 65. Bichakhchyan', '15. Pavol', '16. Michlík']
```